# How to call group using PJSIP

Tags: objective-c, voip, pjsip

How can I make a call between three, four and more accounts using PJSIP API in iOS? To make a call between two account, I use `pjsua_call_make_call` function.

```
char *destUri = "sip:account@example.com";
pj_status_t status;
pj_str_t uri = pj_str(destUri);

status = pjsua_call_make_call(_acc_id, &uri, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error making call", status);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience to run PJSIP on iOS yet (may be there is some restrictions on call count in iOS version of PJSIP?).

Based on my experience of using PJSIP on desktop, you should call all the parties with different calls to `pjsua_call_make_call` (execute `pjsua_call_make_call` 4 times for 4 accounts in group for example). After calls are estabilished, you should connect them in PJSIP's conference bridge all-with-all with [pjsua_conf_connect](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__MEDIA.htm#ga3451304d677e013130dfb9e6b37e3ee6) function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I create an audio recorder and its port. And then I use `pjsua_conf_connect` to connect all `pjsua_conf_port_id` and recorder port

Comment: I am using this code to apply conference call with iOS application. Can you please give more detail about this? Because if I try to use pjsua_call_make_call while already one call is going on , it is giving me erroe code : 70010. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Megha Parmar, I think that [this mailing list answer](http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2008-August/004242.html) is the key for your error (70010). As I remember, iOS has artificial constraints for calls count (like PJ_IOQUEUE_MAX_HANDLES, its about 4 calls by default). You can redefine these defaults somewhere in your project. Hope this helps.

Comment: @hal, you are right my call count was set to 1. As I changed it to 4 , it started working.