# Can i create a conference call or add contact to current call react-native-pjsip?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sip, voip, pjsip

I'm looking for code to initiate conference call using **react-native-pjsip**.
I'm also ready if I need to code for this in android and iOS. I found below two links but not sure how to implement and it is working. Please provide me any related link to conference call.

Android: https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip/issues/135

iOS: [How to call group using PJSIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501442/how-to-call-group-using-pjsip/29203158#29203158)

Answer (score 1):

So, i have my own module wich do have conference call, [React-native-sip-pjsip](https://github.com/willnaoosmith/React-native-sip-pjsip),

The code for the conference is on the file [android/src/main/java/com/carusto/ReactNativePjSip/PjSipService.java](https://github.com/willnaoosmith/React-native-sip-pjsip/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/carusto/ReactNativePjSip/PjSipService.java), and looks like this:

```java
    private void handleCallConference(Intent intent) {
        try {

            List<AudioMedia> mCallsAudioMedia = new ArrayList<>();

            for (PjSipCall currCall : mCalls)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < currCall.getInfo().getMedia().size(); i++) {
                    currCall.unhold();
                    Media media = currCall.getMedia(i);
                    CallMediaInfo mediaInfo = currCall.getInfo().getMedia().get(i);
                    if (mediaInfo.getType() == pjmedia_type.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO && media != null) {
                        AudioMedia audioMedia = AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(media);
                        mCallsAudioMedia.add(audioMedia);

                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mCallsAudioMedia.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mCallsAudioMedia.size(); j++) {
                    if( i != j) {
                        mCallsAudioMedia.get(i).startTransmit(mCallsAudioMedia.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }

            mEmitter.fireIntentHandled(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mEmitter.fireIntentHandled(intent, e);
        }
    }
```

This function will:

> unhold all current calls.

> Make all the current contacts hear each other using `transport`.

So, you can use my code on your own module, or use my module itself.
You can call this function as you call the `makecall` function, and so on (Too much depends of how you're using it).

Comment: Hey thanks Willim for quick and useful answer, I also have query it will work with react-native version 0.63.3?
Any lib or demo which is containing basic demo?